# imblearn error installing smote

Tags: python, class-imbalance, imbalanced-learn

I wanna install smote from imblearn package and I got the Following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-77606507c62c> in <module>()
     66 len(data[data["num"]==0])
     67 #balancing dataset
---> 68 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
     69 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     70 sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     33 """
     34 
---> 35 from .base import FunctionSampler
     36 from ._version import __version__
     37 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in <module>()
     17 from sklearn.utils import check_X_y
     18 
---> 19 from .utils import check_sampling_strategy, check_target_type
     20 from .utils.deprecation import deprecate_parameter
     21 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
      5 from ._docstring import Substitution
      6 
----> 7 from ._validation import check_neighbors_object
      8 from ._validation import check_target_type
      9 from ._validation import check_ratio

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in <module>()
     12 
     13 from sklearn.base import clone
---> 14 from sklearn.neighbors.base import KNeighborsMixin
     15 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
     16 from sklearn.externals import six

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\__init__.py in <module>()
      7 from .kd_tree import KDTree
      8 from .dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
----> 9 from .graph import kneighbors_graph, radius_neighbors_graph
     10 from .unsupervised import NearestNeighbors
     11 from .classification import KNeighborsClassifier, RadiusNeighborsClassifier

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\graph.py in <module>()
      5 # License: BSD 3 clause (C) INRIA, University of Amsterdam
      6 
----> 7 from .base import KNeighborsMixin, RadiusNeighborsMixin
      8 from .unsupervised import NearestNeighbors
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in <module>()
     20 from .kd_tree import KDTree
     21 from ..base import BaseEstimator
---> 22 from ..metrics import pairwise_distances_chunked
     23 from ..metrics.pairwise import PAIRWISE_DISTANCE_FUNCTIONS
     24 from ..utils import check_X_y, check_array, gen_even_slices

ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise_distances_chunked' from 'sklearn.metrics' (C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try quitting and restarting `ipython`. `imblearn` requires `scikit-learn` >= 0.20 and sometimes the ipython runtime loads an older version of `scikit-learn`.

If the issue still persists, then reinstall all packages together to make sure they are compatible with each other.

Comment: I was getting a different import error with SMOTE and this worked for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

to reinstall it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install Tensorflow
```

then,

```
pip install imblearn
```

After the installation restart the system, as The `imblearn.tensorflow` provides utilities to deal with imbalanced dataset in tensorflow, and imblearn uses Tensorflow as backend.